# Pythonic list to string method

Tags: python

So I'm wondering what the most "pythonic" way of turning a list into a string.

For example:

```
string_list = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
# to the string
string = 'hello'
```

I've been using the `''.join(string_list)` method but it just feels near unreadable and roundabout method to do something so simple.

Is there a better way or am I overcomplicating this?

Comment: Believe it or not, that *is* the readable way but it's also a bit of a python thing.

Comment: `''.join(list)` is a very pythonic way already, are you looking for a better efficiency?

Comment: On another note, don't call your list `list`, you are shadowing the builtin.

Comment: Yeah not an efficiency thing, it just feels ugly to me. But if its the usual way!

Comment: @InbarRose It is the most efficient way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is the pythonic way to do it.

Maybe you feel that it should read: `string_list.join('')`. You are [not alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493819/python-join-why-is-it-string-joinlist-instead-of-list-joinstring).

Probably the most important advantage is, that this enables  `.join()` to work with *anything* that is iterable.

If it worked the other way around, each collection would need to implement a `join()` method by themselves. If you were to create your own collection, would you add a `.join()` method? Probably not.

The fact that it is a method of the `str` class means, that it will *always* work. There are no surprises. Read here on [Python and the principle of least astonishment](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/#seemingly-inverse-logic) about `join()` and other things by the `Flask` author Armin Ronacher.

A similar argument can be made for the `len()` function/operator, which can be found at the beginning of the aforementioned article.

Comment: Off-topic comment alert. From the (excellent) linked article: "Decorators are somewhat of a pain because there is a difference between @foo and @foo(). If they were declared in a way that the former means the latter we would all be much happier now. Every time I want to introduce a parameter to a previously parameterless decorator makes me want to hit myself and the author of the decorator PEP with a stick." LOL. Indeed!

Answer (score 4):

Use `''.join(string_list)`. Note that `list` names a built-in type, so you should not use that for variable names. Since Python strings are immutable, you need to construct a new string regardless. `''.join(s)` is the canonical and efficient way to do this in Python.

Comment: isnt there a more efficient way? since i always thought `''.join(s)` is like writing `s[0]+''+s[1]+''+s[2]+''+s[3]...s[x]` ?

Comment: isnt there a way to do `s[0]+s[1]+s[2]..s[x]` ??

Comment: @InbarRose the `+` method creates `n` temporary copies. The `str.join` method reserves required space in a single pre-pass. So the `.join` method will outperform the naive `+` operator for non-trivial cases, especially those cases where there are many strings to join

Comment: The `.join()` string method is actually the most efficient method of assembling a multipart string in Python.  String addition is slow because it creates many strings: first it creates `s[0]+''`, then to that resulting string it adds `s[1]` to create another.  `.join()` only creates a single string.

Comment: yes, i am aware that it does it all in a single pass, the question is, if i am not putting anything between the different parts like `''.join(s)` is there a better way? i can totally understand if `', '.join(s)` were used how its more efficient, but when there is nothing to be placed between the values in the list?

Comment: @InbarRose regardless of how the "gap" is filled, `n` new strings still need to be created, with all but the last being temporary, due to the simple way the `+` operator overload is expanded and handled in the AST

Comment: ah, that makes much more sense now that you say that, something clicked i guess :)

Comment: @InbarRose Also `Py_MEMCPY(p, sep, seplen);` will do a memcpy on a seplen of 0 in the case of `''.join`, so nothing will actually end up being copied.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overcomplicating. Here is from python itself:

```
>>> list = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> sum(list, '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]
```

So, python's recommendation is to use `''.join`.

Comment: this is not what the OP asked. he wants to convert a list of strings into a single string which is made up of all the strings in the list.

Comment: @InbarRose This was the old way of doing that

Comment: Hm, I just delivered python answer on given question (converting list of string into string).