# Converting a list to string in python 2.7

Tags: python

I have a list xline. It is initialized and then appended. But I am getting an error when I run?

```
xline = []
---#append
----
print (''.join(xline)) # Convert list into string
```

Run time error

```
    print (''.join(xline)) # Convert list into string
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show us more code please? More specifically, what are you doing with `pline`?

Comment: `expected string, int found` self explanatory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic list to string method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816685/pythonic-list-to-string-method)

Comment: `print (''.join(map(str, xline)))`

Comment: For debug output, consider the `repr()` function which should give you a string representation for pretty much anything.

Comment: @ozgur how can you format  - say if you want a tab space between the strings - these separated by a comma originally?

Comment: @user5331677 then you can `print '\t'.join(map(str, xline))`

Comment: This is short and sweet - thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str()` to transform each element:

```
print ''.join([str(x) for x in xline])
```

Comment: The above method is more versatile than the map method as I was able to format. I liked map for simplicity but lacks formatting option or I do not know how to format with map.