# The right and elegant way to split a join a string in Python

Tags: python, list, join, split, syntax-error

I have the following list:

```
>>> poly
'C:\\04-las_clip_inside_area\\16x16grids_1pp_fsa.shp'
>>> record
1373155
```

and I wish to create:

```
'C:\\04-las_clip_inside_area\\16x16grids_1pp_fsa_1373155.txt'
```

I wish to split in order to get the part "C:\04-las_clip_inside_area\16x16grids_1pp_fsa16x16grids_1pp_fsa".

I have tried this two-code-lines solution:

```
mylist = [poly.split(".")[0], "_", record, ".txt"]
>>> mylist
['C:\\04-las_clip_inside_area\\16x16grids_1pp_fsa', '_', 1373155, '.txt']
```

from here, reading the example in *[Python join, why is it string.join(list) instead of list.join(string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493819/python-join-why-is-it-string-joinlist-instead-of-list-joinstring)*.

I find this solution to joint, but I get this error message:

```
>>> mylist.join("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'
```

Also if I use:

```
>>> "".join(mylist)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, int found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> from os import path
>>>
>>> path.splitext(poly)
('C:\\04-las_clip_inside_area\\16x16grids_1pp_fsa', '.shp')
>>>
>>> filename, ext = path.splitext(poly)
>>> "{0}_{1}.txt".format(filename, record)
'C:\\04-las_clip_inside_area\\16x16grids_1pp_fsa_1373155.txt'
```

Comment: (+1) splitext seems to be the way to go here to me -- Although you can import `os.path` directly without importing the rest of `os`

Comment: I think this is _the_ way to do what the OP wants. Whenever you want to deal with paths you _must_ take a look at it(it's why it's there!)

Comment: @paolo: thanks. I don't understand why if i try the example of the link: >>>my_list = ["Hello", "world"] >>> print my_list.join("-") i have this error Traceback (most recent call last): File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: @Gianni -- You want `'-'.join(my_list)`.  `join` is a string method, not a list method.  This allows `join` to work with any iterable, not just lists.

Comment: @Gianni Because `join()` method is in the `string` class. Your second example is fine (`"".join(mylist)`), you just have to convert `record` to string. For example, try `"".join([poly.split(".")[0], "_", str(record), ".txt"])`

Answer (score 20):

**[Python join: why is it string.join(list) instead of list.join(string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493819/python-join-why-is-it-string-joinlist-instead-of-list-joinstring)**

So there is

```
"".join(mylist)
```

instead of

```
mylist.join("")
```

There's your error.

To solve your `int/string` problem, convert the int to string:

```
mylist= [poly.split(".")[0],"_",str(record),".txt"]
```

or write directly:

```
"{}_{}.txt".format(poly.split(".")[0], record)
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand why if i try the example: 
>>>my_list = ["Hello", "world"] >>> print my_list.join("-") i have this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: @Gianni - because there is no `list.join(string)`. There is `string.join(list)`. You've read that linked discussion, didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> poly = 'C:\\04-las_clip_inside_area\\16x16grids_1pp_fsa.shp'
>>> record = 1373155
>>> "{}_{}.txt".format(poly.rpartition('.')[0], record)
'C:\\04-las_clip_inside_area\\16x16grids_1pp_fsa_1373155.txt'
```

or if you insist on using `join()`

```
>>> "".join([poly.rpartition('.')[0], "_", str(record), ".txt"])
'C:\\04-las_clip_inside_area\\16x16grids_1pp_fsa_1373155.txt'
```

It's important to use `rpartition()` (or `rsplit()`) as otherwise it won't work properly if the path has any other `'.'`'s in it

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert record into a string.

```
mylist= [poly.split(".")[0],"_",str(record),".txt"]
```