# How does Map work

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a line of code which is:

```
D = {'h' : 'hh' , 'e' : 'ee'}
str = 'hello'
data = ''.join(map(lambda x:D.get(x,x),str))
print data
```

this gives an output -> hheello

I am trying to understand how does map function work here. Does map take each character of
the string and compare it with dictionary key, and give back the corresponding key value?

How does it do for each character here? There is no iteration. Is there any good example to understand this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes individual elements of str. Following is the readable code for the same implementation:

```
D = { 'h' : 'hh' , 'e' : 'ee'}
str = 'hello'
returns = []  # create list for storing return value from function
def myLambda(x): # function does lambda 
    return D.get(x,x)

for x in str: #map==> pass iterable 
    returns.append(myLambda(x)) #for each element get equivalent string from dictionary and append to list

print ''.join(returns) #join for showing result
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no loop because `map` requires an "iterable" (i.e. an object on which you can do an iteration) and does the loop itself.

`map`, if not present natively, could be implemented as:

```
def map(f, it):
    return [f(x) for x in it]
```

or, even more explicitly, as:

```
def map(f, it):
    result = []
    for x in it:
        result.append(f(x))
    return result
```

In Python a string is an iterable, and on iteration loops over the characters in the string. For example

```
map(ord, "hello")
```

returns

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

because those are the character codes for the chars in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Map just applies the function to each item of a list. E.g.,

```
map(lambda x: 10*x, [1,2,3,4])
```

gives

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a map operation works like this:

> **MAP (f,L)** returns **L'**
>
> Input:
>
> - **L** is a list of *n* elements **[ e1 , e2 , ... , en ]**
> - **f** is a function
>
> Output
>
> - **L'** is the list **L** after the application of **f** to each element individually: **[ f(e1) , f(e2) , ... , f(en) ]**

So, in your case, the join operation, [which operates on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493819/python-join-why-is-it-string-joinlist-instead-of-list-joinstring), starts with the empty string and repeatedly concatenates each element **e** obtained in the following way:

> Take a character **x** from **str**; return **D.get(x,x)**

Note that the above (which is the explaining of the map operation) will give you **'hh'** and **'ee'** with input **'h'** and input **'e'** respectively, while it will leave the other characters as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Since `str` is a string, [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) will apply the function (`lambda` in this case) to every item of the string. [`map()][2]` works on iterables and sequences, so it can work in a *string* because a [string is a sequence](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

Try this so you get the idea:

```
str2 = "123"
print map(int, str2)
>>> [1, 2, 3]
```

In this case you are casting each letter in `str2` to `int`:

```
int("1") -> 1
int("2") -> 2
int("3") -> 3
```

and return them in a `list`:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

**Note:** Don't use [Python built-in names](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) as names of variables. Don't use `str` as the name of a variable because you are hiding its built-in implementation. Use `str1`, `my_str` o, `s` ... instead.