# Joining a list of string digits to create an integer Python 3

Tags: python, list, integer, digit

How can I convert this:

```
['2', '3', '1', '4', '1', '4', '2', '3', '3', '2', '4', '1', '4', '1', '3', '2']
```

into this

```
2314142332414132
```

I've tried using the .join method, but I'm quite new to Python and need some help using it. I've also tried working with re.sub, string.replace, but none of them worked. Any help?

Comment: Don't just say what you tried to use; show exactly how you tried to use it.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote a question that says "I'm quite new" right in the middle of it??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
values = ['2', '3', '1', '4', '1', '4', '2', '3', '3', '2', '4', '1', '4', '1', '3', '2']
value = ''.join(values)
```

If you want to have an int value, you can cast the resulting string to int:

```
value = int(value)
```

Comment: Thanks, with the `value = ''.join(values)` you solved my day.

Answer (score 4):

```
result = int(''.join(['1','2']))
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493819/python-join-why-is-it-string-joinlist-instead-of-list-joinstring).

Comment: Thanks, my error was about putting `''.join(my_list)`instead of `result =''.join(my_list)`.

Comment: This is very important conceptually. Python's variables don't have type, but its values do. You can never "transform" a value in-place in a way that changes its type; thus `''.join(my_list)` cannot possibly change `my_list` from being a list into being a string. Most built-in functions create new values rather than changing their input values, even if the returned thing is of the same type.