# turning string into a mixed list of chars and digits

Tags: python

how to make a string like this: '20P20P20P20' into a list like this [20, 'P', 20, 'P', 20, 'P', 20]

```
my_string = '20P20P20P20'
list_of_steps = list(my_string)
    for step in list_of_steps:
        if step.isdigit():
            new_map.append(int(step))
        else:
            new_map.append(step)
```

It turns into a digit, but how to join digits that are next to each other into one?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression to split the string into chunks.

```
import re

my_string = '20P20P20P20'
lst = [
    int(part) if part.isdigit() else part
    for part in re.findall(r"\d+|\D+", my_string)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't append each digit to `new_map` right away. First collect them in a temporary list until you find a letter again. Then combine the digits in the temporary list to a complete number and append that number to `new_map`.

Don't forget to clear the temporary list before you collect the next set of digits.

For example:

- `'2'`: append to temporary list, it is now `['2']`
- `'0'`: append to temporary list, it is now `['2', '0']`
- `'P'`: convert temporary list `['2', '0']` to the number 20

  - append 20 to `new_map`
  - append 'P' to `new_map`
  - clear temprary list, it is now `[]`
- `'2'`: append to temporary list, it is now `['2']`
- and so on...

For converting the temporary list of digits to a number, see [Joining a list of string digits to create an integer Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077881/joining-a-list-of-string-digits-to-create-an-integer-python-3).