# How does .join work in Python?

Tags: python

I want to display each row of a SQL query result on a webpage.  I found some code, but I don't understand what this line does.

```
u"<br>".join([u"{0}".format(row.combination) for row in salt])
```

How does the `.join` method give me the desired result?

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join)?

Comment: Moderately related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493819/python-join-why-is-it-string-joinlist-instead-of-list-joinstring

Comment: Also, uh `u"{0}".format(row.combination)` ....isn't that just `unicode(row.combination)`?

Comment: "x".join(iterable) join all items of iterable spacing it by x. It put "x" between each pair of items of iterable

Comment: You're wetting your feet with Django and you don't understand strings?

Comment: As being a beginner I may have unintentionally skipped some topics . Thanks for the doc  .

Answer (score 2):

Best to run a python shell and test it, such as:

```
>>> "x".join (["a", "b", "c"])
'axbxc'
>>> "abc".join (["M"])
'M'
```

The "x" was used as the thing in between the values in the iterable.  Next time "abc" was used in between, except there was only one value, so there was no in between needed.

Then refer to the docs as per CoryKramer comment.