# Python script for: Add "ing" to any word that is in text, if word ends with "ing" add "ly" to it (ex: gging = ggingly)

Tags: python, string, list

This is my code so far:

```
 lista = 'Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically consis'
 n = lista.split()
 m= ''

def adding(n):
for s in n:
    if s.endswith('ing'):
        s +='ly'
    else:
        s +='ing'
    return s
print(adding(n))
```

I should use `.join` somewhere, but I can't figure it out.
Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/493819/3768871

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to loop through `n`, the list you are taking in the function. Also make a new list for output. Here is an example:

```
def adding(lst):
    out = []
    for word in lst:
        if word.endswith("ing"):
            out.append(word+"ly")
        else:
            out.append(word+"ing")
     return out.join(" ")

print(adding(n()))
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you mean by that. This is my version, improvement would be to ignore punctuation. Don't know how yet.Check above for my edited version.