# I am getting an error as list object has no attribute 'join'

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
ueid_list = [['0'],['0','1'],['0','1','2']...]

corefiles(str type): {"core0.log", "core4.log","core3.log","core7.log"}

RNTI(str type):{"0x0000","0x003f",...}
```

The below code has a loop that iterates over
the above three by taking values one after
other in the function and prints details accordingly...

My code:

```
 for a in (ueid_list):

  for b in (corefiles):

      for c in (rnti):

          getUeLinesFromcorefiles(b,a,c)
```

The above *getueid* function is defined as:

```
def getUeLinesFromcorefiles(filenames, ueid, rnti)
.
.
.
.
.
```

This is showing an error:

> as attributeerror: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

How can I deal with this error?

Comment: Where are you calling `join`?  Post a [mcve]

Comment: The order of parameters to the function `getUeLinesFromcorefiles` appears to be incorrect, should it be `getUeLinesFromcorefiles(b,a,c)`(or maybe your for loops are in the incorrect order)

Comment: If you had chosen better names than a, b, c, your calls would have been `getUeLinesFromcorefiles(ueid, corefile, rnti)`.  The first error is that ueid and corefile are the wrong way round relative to the function definition.  The second is that the function definition takes filenameS - are you sure you aren't supposed to pass it the whole of `corefiles`

Comment: When i mentioned the order as getUeLinesFromcorefiles(corefiles, ueid_list, rnti) it shows an error as int() can't convert non string with explicit base at a condition in the function getUeLinesFromcorefiles() where RNTi= int(rnti, 16).

Comment: See [python - Why is it string.join(list) instead of list.join(string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493819).

Answer (score 87):

The main question is not relevant, but the title is the error I got.

I mixed up the syntax trying to join a list of strings. I was doing this:

```
list_of_str.join(' ')
```

when I should do this:

```
' '.join(list_of_str)
```

Comment: This is the most unintuitive design choice I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

.join should be applied on strings. You are trying that on list. Basically, `a` in the *for* loop is a list.