# What is the most memory efficient way to join a list into a string in micropython?

Tags: list, join, micropython

What is the most memory-efficient way to join a list into a string in MICROPYTHON?

the list object in MICROPYTHON doesn't have the 'join' function, so I would like to know if there's any memory-efficient way to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with standard Python, `join` is a method of strings not of lists. See:

[Python join: why is it string.join(list) instead of list.join(string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493819/python-join-why-is-it-string-joinlist-instead-of-list-joinstring)

and/or

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-is-join-a-string-method-instead-of-a-list-or-tuple-method

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked, there's indeed a join function from the str class to join the list

e.g.

```
",".join(["a","b","c"])
```

Comment: If this answers your question you should mark it as such, else the question remains unanswered