# Understanding Python sequence

Tags: python-3.x, sequence

I am doing a hackerrank example called Flipping bits where given a list of 32 bit unsigned integers. Flip all the bits (1->0 and 0->1) and return the result as an unsigned integer.
The correct code is:

```
def flippingBits(n):
    seq = format(n, '032b')
    return int(''.join(['0' if bit == '1' else '1' for bit in seq]), 2)
```

I dont understand the last line, what does the ''. part do? and why is there a ,2 at the end?

I have understood most of the code but need help in understanding the last part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it string.join(list) instead of list.join(string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493819/why-is-it-string-joinlist-instead-of-list-joinstring)

Answer (score 0):

> what does the ''. part do

`''` represents an empty string which will be used as separator to join collection elements into string (some examples can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp))

> and why is there a ,2 at the end?

from `int` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> **class int(x=0)**
> **class int(x, base=10)**
> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x

In this case it will parse the string provided in binary format (i.e. with base 2) into int.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below explanation helps:

```
def flippingBits(n):
  seq = format(n, '032b')  # change the format from base 10 to base 2 with 32bit size unsigned integer into string
  return int(''.join(['0' if bit == '1' else '1' for bit in seq]), 2)
# ['0' if bit == '1' else '1' for bit in seq]  => means: build a list of characters from "seq" string
# in which whenever there is 1 convert it to 0, and to 1 otherwise; then
# ''.join(char_list) => means: build string by joining characters in char_list
# without space between them ('' means empty delimiter); then
# int(num_string, 2) => convert num_string from string to integer in a base 2
```

Notice that you can do the bit flipping by using bit-wise operations without converting to string back and forth.

```
def flippingBits(n):
  inverted_n = ~n    # flip all bits from 0 to 1, and 1 to 0
  return inverted_n+2**32  # because the number is a signed integer, the most significant bit should be flipped as well
```

Comment: Oops, *since bit size of an integer in python is 32 by default*... Are you really sure? It was indeed true in old Python 2 versions, but in current Python3.x versions, the integer type is a multiprecision type than can use as many bits as required. Your code works fine anyway for any positive integer below 2^32 which is OP's concern.

Comment: Thank you @SergeBallesta for pointing out this. The answer has been corrected.